# Troubles with trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

Somebody knows what is the error in my sintaxys?

```
CREATE TRIGGUER safe_pass AFTER UPDATE ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF OLD.clave <> NEW.clave THEN
    UPDATE usuario SET Clave = SHA1(MD5(NEW.clave)) WHERE id_usuario = NEW.id_usuario;
END IF;

END;

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGUER safe_pass AFTER UPDATE ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF OLD.clave <' at line 1
```

I have experience with SQL Server, but MySQL is a Headache for me.
The version of MySQL that I have is MySQL Database Version 5.0.51b.

Thanks and regards

---

Sorry, I'm really sorry for my mistake, I made the change Infinity suggested me.

Error SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER safe_pass AFTER UPDATE ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF OLD.clave <> NEW.clave THEN
UPDATE usuario SET Clave = SHA1( MD5( NEW.clave ) ) WHERE id_usuario = NEW.id_usuario

END IF;
END;
```

And the result is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 6
```

Thanks Siride, I try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER safe_pass AFTER UPDATE ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF OLD.clave <> NEW.clave THEN
UPDATE usuario SET Clave = SHA1( MD5( NEW.clave ) ) WHERE id_usuario = NEW.id_usuario;

END IF;
END;
```

And the result was:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

---

I had to do it from the console, and the final script is:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER safe_pass BEFORE UPDATE ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF OLD.clave <> NEW.clave THEN
    SET NEW.clave = SHA1(MD5(NEW.clave));
END IF;

END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: finally I solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem. I had to do it from the console, and the final script is:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER safe_pass BEFORE UPDATE ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF OLD.clave <> NEW.clave THEN
    SET NEW.clave = SHA1(MD5(NEW.clave));
END IF;

END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be pretty fine with MySQL, you just try to find the `TRIGGUER` keyboard with `TRIGGER` :-)

Comment: Hahaha sorry, I'm really sorry. i did the change, but doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `TRIGGUER` problem, you left off the semi-colon at the end of your `UPDATE` statement inside the `IF`.